# integer stored as float

Tags: math, ieee-754

I have some questions regarding integers and floats:

1. Can I store every **32-bit** unsigned integer value into a **64-bit** IEEE floating point value (such that when I assign the double value back to an int the int will contain the original value)?
2. What are the smallest (magnitude wise) positive and negative integer values that cannot be stored in a **32-bit** IEEE floating point value (by the same definition as in 1)?
3. Do the answers to these questions depend on language used?

//edit: I know these questions sound a bit like from some test but I'm asking about these things because I need to make some decisions on a dataformat definition

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes, you can store a 32-bit integer a 64-bit `double` without information loss. The mantissa has 53 bits of  precision, which is enough.
2. A 32-bit `float` has a 24-bit mantissa, so the maximum and minimum integers with a unique representation are 2^24-1 and -2^24+1 (16777215 and -16777215). Greater numbers don't have a unique representation; for example `16777216 == (float)16777217`.
3. If you assume the language follows IEEE-754, it doesn't depend on the language.

Comment: Hey Joni - does that mean if I will assign 2^24 to a double and then to an int, the int will contain 2^24-1?

Comment: If you assign 2^24 to a `float` and then to `int` you will get back 2^24. But, if you assign 2^24+1 to a `float` and then to `int` you'll also get back 2^24. That is, if you get back 2^24 you can't know which number it was originally.

Comment: ah yeas, i meant to say float not double. Okay this makes sense, thanks! :)